# Redis ZSETS get element with highest score and remove it

Tags: redis

I am trying to implement a LIFO (Last In First Out) stack using Redis ZETS. I score is the unix epoch timestamp of insertion of element into the set. I need to implement the POP operation. The way I could figure out was to use

```
ZREVRANGEBYSCORE <key> <current timestamp> 0 limit 0 1
```

Start from current timestamp till zero, fetch only one element.

However, to remove the member, I will have to call the `ZREM` command.

Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to achieve in a single call ?

Also, is it possible to expire individual members of the sorted set ? So far I could find expiration to work on keys only. Not sure if it can be applied on elements as well.

**UPDATE** I figured a workaround for expiration. I can provide the min timestamp while fetching in my `ZREVRANGEBYSCORE` call which will serve my purpose.

Comment: y can't you use a simple queue using lpush and lpop which is a single call. Is there any necessity in storing timestamp? Any how you are retrieving the last inserted element alone rit?

Comment: I was thinking of a scalable service across different geographies and Elasticache came to mind, which has Redis and Memcached. Could you suggest any alternative where I don't have to spend a lot of time in infrastructure ?